# fallo de caracteres especiales sólo entre palabras

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, utf-8

estoy experimentando algo que no me había pasado nunca.

tengo el siguiente datatable:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando pulso el botón de editar de la primera línea, por ejemplo, levanto un modal para poder modificar únicamente la columna Comportamiento, de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si cambio el valor Pepi??o por Pepiño al pulsar el botón actualizar me guarda en base de datos el valor "Pepi??o" en cambio si escribo "Pepi ñ o", con la ñ separada por blancos, me lo guarda correctamente.

Es como si al ir los caracteres dentro de una palabra los escribiera mal.

También me pasa con las tildes.

Estoy usando la codificación UTF-8 tanto en el código como en la base de datos.

Les ha pasado alguna vez?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola. ¿Puedes añadir código? No vemos el proceso para tratar los datos hasta la query de inserción en BD.

Comment: Saludos. Un tiempo me ocurrio; agrege los meta que indiquen utf-8 y se corrigió; además que tus datos esten guardados correctamente.

Comment: intenta insertar datos nuevamente después de que hayas hecho los cambios a utf-8, ya que puede que tus inserciones anteriores hayan quedado con los símbolos que muestras en tus imágenes. Es todo lo que te puedo decir ya que no tienes código añadido en tu pregunta

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código donde estás haciendo tu registro?